# "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting" when entering window

Tags: python, tkinter

I was following the question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533532/how-to-center-a-tkinter-window-and-retain-the-fit-to-children-behavior) by [Bryan Oakley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7432/bryan-oakley) but despite the asker saying that it works, it gives me this error.

```
   root.geometry("+%d+%d" % (rootsize + (x, y)))
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code I am using:

```
w = root.winfo_screenwidth()
h = root.winfo_screenheight()
rootsize = tuple(int(_) for _ in root.geometry().split('+')[0].split('x'))
x = w/2 - rootsize[0]/2
y = h/2 - rootsize[1]/2
root.geometry("+%d+%d" % (rootsize + (x, y)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding elements to that `tuple`, not adding *to each* element in the `tuple`.

```
>>> a = (1,2)
>>> b = (3,4)
>>> a+b
(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

You want something like the following instead, which puts each `tuple` side by side, iterates through each pair of elements, then finds their `sum()` (printed for clarity):

```
>>> print(*map(sum, zip(a,b)), sep='\n')
4
6
```

Which would be this in your code:

```
root.geometry("+%d+%d" % (rootsize[0]+x, rootsize[1]+y))
```

Answer (score 0):

The string being processed has two representation placeholders: `"+%d+%d"` but you're passing it only one value `rootsize + (x, y)` - this will evaluate to just one expression.

So do one of the following based on what `root.geometry()` is expecting:

```
root.geometry("+%d+%d" % (rootsize, (x, y)))  # two separate args
# Or...
root.geometry("+%d" % (rootsize + (x, y)))    # one arg
```

I'm assuming `(x, y)` is meant to represent a tuple. Other options are:

```
"+%d" % (rootsize + (x, y))  # if rootsize is an instance of a class with
                             # `__add__` defined and handles tuples added
                             # to it; returning an int/numeric result, not
                             # a tuple. seems UNLIKELY. see next...

"+%d+%d" % (rootsize + x, rootsize + y)  # two arguments each adding rootsize with x or y

"+%d+%d+%d" % (rootsize, x, y)  # three arguments
```

(Without knowing what `root.geometry()` expects, can't advise further.)