# Why doesn't this centre the window?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using this code to centre my screen as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533532/how-to-center-a-tkinter-window-and-retain-the-fit-to-children-behavior) post and my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33932516/typeerror-not-all-arguments-converted-during-string-formatting-when-entering/33932698#33932698) but to my surprise it doesn't centre the window exactly. It puts it in the lower right hand corner not the centre exactly. Why is this?

```
 top1=Toplevel(root)
 w = top1.winfo_screenwidth()
 h = top1.winfo_screenheight()
 topsize = tuple(int(_) for _ in top1.geometry().split('+')[0].split('x'))
 x = w/2 - topsize[0]/2
 y = h/2 - topsize[1]/2
 top1.geometry("+%d+%d" % (topsize[0]+x, topsize[1]+y))
```

> Final Solution by Steven Summers

```
import Tkinter as tk


def center_window(win):
    w = win.winfo_screenwidth()
    h = win.winfo_screenheight()
    x = w/2 - win.winfo_width()/1-150
    y = h/2 - win.winfo_height()/1-200
    win.geometry("+%d+%d" % (x, y))

root = tk.Tk()
top1 = tk.Toplevel(root)
top1.title('TopLevel Window 1')
top1.minsize(300, 300)

b = tk.Label(top1, text='Here is a Label')
b.pack()
l = tk.Button(top1, text='Click Me')
l.pack()

top1.after(1, lambda: center_window(top1))

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `root.after(delay, command)` to run this. When you create the widget and it tries to initialize, the size is 1x1. Which is why your values are not correct when placing it. Also as mentioned in the answer to the question referenced, use `.winfo_width() and .winfo_height()` instead of going through the geometry to get the values.

```
import tkinter as tk


def center_window(win):
    w = win.winfo_screenwidth()
    h = win.winfo_screenheight()
    x = w/2 - win.winfo_width()/2
    y = h/2 - win.winfo_height()/2
    win.geometry("+%d+%d" % (x, y))

root = tk.Tk()
top1 = tk.Toplevel(root)
top1.title('TopLevel Window 1')
top1.minsize(300, 300)

b = tk.Label(top1, text='Here is a Label')

top1.after(1, lambda: center_window(top1))

l = tk.Button(top1, text='Click Me')

b.pack()
l.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution doesn't work. It gives no errors but positions the window in the same spot as before.

Comment: I am using Python 3 and running just exactly that code centered the top1 window on the screen for me.

Comment: Just did some testing and it seems you want to assign at least 1 widget to the Toplevel widget before calling `.after()` otherwise it places differently. Doesn't seem to matter if you pack before / after and add other widgets either

Comment: very sorry but this code you posted *still* does the same thing. I can't see why though because it all seems to make sense...

Comment: Do you know if it's changing the position at all? Try changing some values like `/4` on all and see if it goes to the lop left. Otherwise I could only suggest using some `+ -` values to `geometry` to move it that little bit over

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
top1.geometry("+%d+%d" % (x, y))
```

Comment: For some reason it is exactly the same.

Comment: I think that the top left corner of the window is in the centre so I think that it positions that corner instead of the centre of the window.